# Synchronize two button's styles in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I have two buttons in my DataGrid's Row.

1. Edit --- symbol : pencil,  Save ---- symbol : floppy
2. Delete --- symbol : big cross, Cancel --- symbol : small cross

Case 1. I clicked the Edit Button, At this time 2 things should happen.....

1. Edit Button should be replaced with save button. I mean the symbol should change to floppy.
2. Delete button should be replaced with cancel button.

Case 2. I click the save button:

1. Save Button should be replaced with Edit button.
2. Cancel Button should be replaced with Delete button.

Case 3. When I click cancel button:

1. Save Button should be replaced with Edit Button.
2. Cancel button should be replaced with Delete Button.

Case 4. When I click delete button:

1. No style changes.........

I have successfully implemented the first point of case 1. Here is the XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="EditSaveButton">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="32" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="32" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NoramlEditButtonBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource EditButtonPathData}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource NoramlEditButtonBorderBrush}" Padding="5,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="3">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="{StaticResource NoramlEditButtonShadowDepth}" 
                                          Color="{StaticResource NoramlEditButtonShadowColor}"
                                          BlurRadius="{StaticResource NoramlEditButtonBlurRadius}" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Path x:Name="buttonSymbol" Data="{TemplateBinding Content}" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Height="24" Width="24" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" 
                                                  Color="{Binding Background.Brush,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                  BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedEditButtonBorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="{StaticResource PressedEditButtonShadowDepth}" 
                                                  Color="{StaticResource PressedEditButtonShadowColor}" 
                                                  BlurRadius="{StaticResource PressedEditButtonBlurRadius}" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledEditButtonBorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="{StaticResource DisabledEditButtonShadowDepth}" 
                                                  Color="{StaticResource DisabledEditButtonShadowColor}" 
                                                  BlurRadius="{StaticResource DisabledEditButtonBlurRadius}" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource SaveButtonPathData}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NoramlSaveButtonBorderBrush}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If somebody gives me the answer to the second point of case 1, then I will try to accomplish other cases my-self.

Thanks.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you are approaching this is adding extra complication to it. Instead of two buttons you actually want four buttons, but only two are visible at any time.

I would have a Boolean value IsInEdit and use it to bind the visibility of the buttons (visbility converter for edit/delete, inverted visibility converter for save/cancel)

On save or cancel `IsInEdit = false` and on edit `IsInEdit = true`

Comment: Can you please explain more about IsInEdit and the converters?

Comment: IsInEdit would be a property you create on your datacontext (viewmodel, view, whatever you are using). The visibility converter would be an IValueConverter that converts true to Visible and false to Collapsed, Inverted visibility converter would be an IValueConverter that converts true to Collapsed and false to Visible. http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: Thanks, i will try it and let you know.

Comment: I have tried to implement the code as you suggested. At first sight I thought it works fine. But just after a moment I noticed that when I click on edit button it is replaced by Save button. That behavior is good. But it replaces edit button with save button in all the rows. But I want it to be replaced just in the row in which I clicked the edit button.

Comment: Then IsInEdit need to exist in the datacontext of a single row

Comment: I didn't understand your above comment, but I have done it using styles. Thanks for the great answer......